# IIS rewrite rule to add querystring to .css and .js references in ASP.net pages?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, iis, url-rewriting

Is it possible to append a query string to CSS and JS file references (e.g., "foo.css" => "foo.css?v=", "goo.js" => "goo.js?v=", where  is, say, "1.2.3") as part of an inbound rule?  If so, how?

We need to be able to force clients to ask for the latest versions of the CSS and JS files after releasing.  A rewrite rule seems like a good place to do this, but I don't any documentation or message boards posts on doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a rewrite rule, you need an HTTP filter. 
 It would need to dynamically parse and rewrite the requests on the HTTP stream.

[MSDN documentation](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/10/20/httpfilter.html)

[O'Reilly sample](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/10/20/httpfilter.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.  What I'm doing right now is rewriting requests to foo.css to {R:1)?v=blah which seems to work, although the absence of errors doesn't necessarily imply that I have it 100%.

Comment: Wow...everything in that article (both links are to the same article) seems to be arguing against handling this scenario with an HTTP filter.  The term "peril" is mentioned several times in reference to doing any response manipulation. :)

Comment: The documentation is dated 2003. Back then there was no http.sys or integrated managed pipe-line. IIS has evolved greatly since where ASP.Net modules/filters are more integrated. But leaky code is dangerous so cleanup your memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an outbound rule so that the cache(s) request a new file when the verison number changes.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with the following rewrite rule for IIS. All you need to do is change the version number when you make an update. If you have any build automation you might be able to automate it there.

```
<rewrite>

  <rules>
    <rule name="JS versioning" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*).js" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="version=3911" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}.js?version=3911" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>

</rewrite>
```

Essentially, any requests for a url ending with .js are intercepted and redirected to the same url but with a querystring with the version number appended. A subsequent condition is needed to ignore urls that already have the querystring, otherwise it will go into an infinite rewrite loop.

As you want to version css files too, you could either update the match url to a regular expression that matches both js and css, or create a separate rule that does the same but targets css files instead.